# Present Perfect and Past Perfect Continuous in the same sentence

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Can I use both Present Perfect and Past Perfect Continuous in the same sentence?

> Apparently the army had been trying to advance last night but has been stopped by the enemy.

The reasons:

1. Present Perfect - The army has been stopped and didn't try to advance again.
2. Past Perfect Continuous - The attempt preceded the stop. A past action occurred before another past action.

Comment: You'd be more likely to find the past perfect continuous followed by the simple past, "had been trying ... but *was stopped* by the enemy", or a combination of present perfect continuous and present perfect:  "has been trying ... but has been stopped".  The past perfect is normally placed in relation to a discrete action in the past.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: The use of past perfect continuous followed by present perfect doesn't jar my ear in this case. I would be unlikely to write it that way, but "had been trying" reinforces preemptively the idea of the army having been stopped.

Comment: @Robusto.  If you're going to use the present perfect with "has been stopped", you'd use the past continuous with "The army was trying to advance last night".   There's no need for the past perfect in that case.  "The army was trying last night ... but has been stopped."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: True, there's no need. But there is no need for a lot of the constructions people use when speaking. And it still would function the way I said it would.

Comment: It strikes my ear as marginal to use the present perfect as the expression of time in relation to which the past perfect is situated. Change **but** to **until** and the issue becomes glaring. *They had been trying to douse the flames until the fuel tank has caught fire.*